# Прозрачная сеть на DIR-655

Tags: wifi, router

Есть роутер DIR-655, относительно старенький, но подходящий по параметрам и мощности. Необходимо его настроить так, чтобы он продолжал прозрачно сеть (LAN), т.е. работал как обычный свитч, но и позволял через WiFi входить в тот же LAN. На данный момент работает либо LAN (192.168.0.0/24), либо WiFi через WAN (192.168.1.0/24). Если не понятно описал проще: нужно объединить WAN и LAN порты. Либо WiFi вывести в LAN.

Делал подобное на Keenetik III, но там гораздо больше возможностей.